# Read Wifi Information on iOS

Tags: ios, networking, network-programming

I want to read information about my network, router address wifi encrypting, but not the password, and some more information. On my iPhone in a app.
Have someone a good idea how can I handle that?
THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html), the official Apple's documentation on the Reachability library.

There are some examples to show you how this works.

Comment: I dont understand this example, I cant find how can I read the SSID or more, I read a little bit about a Apple80211 but I cant find some stuff about this library, but thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk Check this question

Comment: They only connect to a host, but don't read anything, correct? but I am looking for reading, in the network